# Generating a random matrix with non-static constraints

Tags: matrix, random, non-static

I would like to generate a random matrix with constraints on both rows and columns in MATLAB. But the problem is I have two parameters for this constraints which are not fix for each element. For explanation, consider the mxn matrix P = [P1 ; P2; ...; Pm], and 2 other vectors lambda and Mu with m and n elements, respectively. 
Consider lambda as [lambda(1), lambda(2), ..., lambda(m)] and Mu as [Mu(1), Mu2, ..., Mu(n)]

lamda and Mu should have this constraints:

1. sum of lambda(s) < sum of Mu(s).

,Now for the random matrix P:

2. each element of the matrix(P[j,i]) should be equal or greater than zero.
3. sum of the elements of each row is equal to one (i.e. for the row of j: sigma_i(P[j,i] = 1)
4. for each column j, sum of the production of each element with the correspond lambda(j) is less than the correspond element in the Mu vector (i.e.Mu(i)). i.e. for the column of i: sigma_j(P[j,i]*lambda(j)) < Mu(i)

I have tried coding all these constraints but because the existence of lambda and Mu vectors, just one of the constraints of 3 or 4 can be feasible. May you please help me for coding this matrix.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

There could be values of `Mu` and `Lambda` that does not allow any value of `P[i,j]`.

For each row-vector `v`:

- Constraint 3 means the values are constrained to the hyper-plane `v.1 = 1` (A)
- Constraint 4 means the values are constrained to the half-space `v.Lambda < m` (H), where `m` is the element of `Mu` corresponding to the current row.

Constraint 1 does not guarantee that these two constraint generates a non-empty solution space.

To verify that the solution-space is non-empty, the easiest method is by checking each corner of hyper-plane A (`<1,0,0,...>`, `<0,1,0,...>`, ...). If at least one of the corners qualify for constraint 4, the solution-space is non-empty.

Having said that; Assuming the solution-space is non-empty, you could generate values matching those constraints by:

1. Generate random vector with elements 0 ≤ `vi` ≤ 1.
2. Scale by dividing by the sum of the elements.
3. If this vector does not qualify for constraint 4, repeat from step 1.
4. Once you have `n` such vectors, combine them as rows into a matrix.

The speed of this algorithm depends on how large volume of hyper-plane A is contained inside the half-space H. If only 1% is contained, it would expected to require 100 iterations for that row.

Comment: @Mary If this solved your problem, please click the checkmark above to the left.